# The pipe "noComma" could not be found

Tags: angular

I created a custom pipe named: "noComma".
I tried creating a PipeModule and put the NoCommaPipe in declarations, and exports, and put the PipeModule in the imports of app.module.ts, but the error still occurs.

NoCommaPipe.ts:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
    name: 'noComma'
})

export class NoCommaPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(val: number): string {
        let transformedVal: string;
        if(val === undefined || val === null) {
            transformedVal = ""
        } else {
            transformedVal = val.toString().replace(/,/g, "");
        }
        return transformedVal;
    }
}
```

PipeModule.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NoCommaPipe } from './NoCommaPipe';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        NoCommaPipe
    ],
    exports: [
        NoCommaPipe
    ],
    imports: [
        IonicModule
    ]
})
export class PipeModule {
    static forRoot() {
        return {
            ngModule: PipeModule,
            providers: [],
        };
     }    
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { PipeModule } from '../app/local/pipe/PipeModule';

@NgModule({
imports: [PipeModule.forRoot()]})
```

Comment: One error is: NoCommaPipe.ts should be no-comma.pipe.ts and PipeModule.ts should be pipe.module.ts

Comment: Check the place which you are trying to put 'noComma' pipe. Is it belongs to AppModule